# Moving parent DIV without affecting child DIVs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have DIV and some DIVs inside it, with attribute "position:absolute". Sizes and coordinates of all elements are known and fixed. I have to move parent DIV, but user must think that all child DIVs visually stayed on their old places.

It seems to be easy, but coordinates of all inside DIVs have to be changed too, and exactly by the distance of the parent DIV's movement (the distance is known, 20px for example).

I've tried to change CSS of the parent DIV and in the loop to change coordinates of all child elements, but it doesn't look good - I still can see how child elements are moving (movement is fast, but not invisible). I would like with one simple action to move parent DIV, but all inside DIVs changed their positions automatically and no one could notice that. How can I do that? Performance is important.

Code example:

```
<div id="parent" style="position:absolute; top:50px; left:100px; width:500px; height:300px;">
    <div id="child1" style="position:absolute; top:10px; left:15px; width:20px; height:20px;"></div>
    <div id="child2" style="position:absolute; top:10px; left:55px; width:20px; height:20px;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Post your code please

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a code sample of what you have tried so far so we can see what's involved.

Comment: Added code example to the main post

Comment: If the position of the children uses the position of the parent element as reference point (which it will, if the parent itself is positioned), then you will have to adjust the children’s positions. Probably there’s easier ways to get what you actually _want to achieve_ here – but you failed to describe that. Not moving an actual parent, but an element that is independent from the others, and only _placed behind_ them to achieve the same effect visually or something …

Comment: Sorry, for me it was looking understandably - I need to move "parent", but "child1" and "child2" visually must stay on their old places on the screen

Comment: Please tell how are you changing the position of the parent div. Is it a javascript code.

Comment: Yes, it's javaScript: 

`eee.style.left = (parseInt(eee.style.left) + 100) + "px";`

But it is OK to change that, it doesn't matter how to do that

Comment: 1) save your parent's original x y. 2) in every parent's position readjustment, add to every child's x the parent_original_x-parent_current_x and child's y parent_original_y-parent_current_y

Comment: @qwerty007 what does it mean `I have to move parent DIV, but user must **think that all child DIVs visually stayed on their old places**`

Comment: @Sharky, I've tried that, in a loop for all child elements - but eyes still can notice that childDIV moves to the new place (following parent DIV) and then returns back. I want it to be invisible

Comment: @ozil, it means that child DIV visually must stay on screen's old place, but will have new (absolute) coordinates

Comment: @qwerty007 how will it have new coordinates if child DIV must stay on screen's old place

Comment: @ozil, if you move "parent" to the left by 20px and "child1" to the right by 20px - "child" visually will be on the old place but will have new coordinates (+20px)

Comment: ok, do this: clone your parent div. the clone and the original div are on the same position. give clone div higher z-index so its on top of parent div. hide the parent div with `display:none;` and do what i said before (moving and readjusting child divs.) when moving is finished, make the original parent div visible again and hide the clone div (or destroy it). this will eliminate the "flickering" (but during the process the user will interact with the cloned elements.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this for any arbitrary item (i.e., without knowing its starting position, how many children it has or those children's starting positions) you wish my using CSS's `translateX` [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) function - shift the parent to the right by a given number of pixels and then use the negative of that number to shift the children left, giving the appearance that they are static.

I've provided a few examples below, the first 2 are triggered by a JavaScript event (for the sake of simplicity, they're both triggered by clicking the one button), with the first one just "jumping" across and the second using `transition` to animate across, the second 2 are triggered using mouse actions in CSS, the first of them on `:hover` and the second on `:focus`.

[Here's a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6ccvvqqo/) if you want to play around with it.

**UPDATE:** [Here's another Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n33s7yb7/) with the parent moving left on every click of the button.

```js
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click",function(event){
    var divs=document.querySelectorAll(".event"),x=divs.length;
    while(x--)
        divs[x].classList.toggle("shift");
    event.preventDefault();
},0);
```

```css
/** PARENTS **/
.move{
    border:2px solid #000;
    height:70px;
    padding:40px 10px 10px;
    position:absolute;
    width:250px;
}
.move:first-of-type{left:20px;top:50px;}
.move:nth-of-type(2){left:30px;top:130px;}
.move:nth-of-type(3){left:40px;top:210px;}
.move:nth-of-type(4){left:50px;top:290px;}
/** CHILDREN **/
.move>div{
    background:#000;
    height:20px;
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    width:20px;
}
.move>div:first-child{left:15px;}
.move>div:nth-child(2){left:45px;}
.move>div:nth-child(3){left:75px;}
.move>div:nth-child(4){left:105px;}
/** ANIMATION **/
.animate,.animate>div{
    transition:transform .5s linear;
}
/** TRANSFORMATION **/
.shift,.hover:hover,.focus:focus{
    transform:translateX(100px);
}
.shift>div,.hover:hover>div,.focus:focus>div{
    transform:translateX(-100px);
}
/** MISC **/
button{
    top:10px;
    left:10px;
    position:relative;
}
*{box-sizing:border-box;line-height:20px;margin:0;outline:0;}
```

```html
<button id="button">Click Me</button>
<div class="move event">
    <div></div>
    <p>I just jump across</p>
</div>
<div class="move event animate">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <p>I transition across</p>
</div>
<div class="move hover animate">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <p>Hover over me</p>
</div>
<div class="move focus animate" tabindex="-1">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <p>Click on me</p>
</div>
```

Comment: very good example, I've checked it - but unfortunately div's coordinates are not being changed, both parent's and children's. "left=45px" stays "left=45px" after transformation. Later I will need to move parent DIV again by 100px and I won't be able to append "shift" class again 20 times, so position must be changed

Comment: @qwerty007 is this more along the lines of what you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/n33s7yb7/

Comment: Almost, Shaggy. As was mentioned in the main post - I've tried to change CSS of the parent DIV and in the loop to change coordinates of all child elements, but it doesn't look good - I still can see how child elements are moving to the new place and back to the old. So I'm looking for a solution without modifying every child manually in a loop, or something else

Comment: I'm beginning to think this may be a hardware issue, rather than a CSS issue. I see no visible physical movement of the child elements during the transition. Anyway, unless using `position:fixed` for the children is a feasible option for you, you're not going to be able to do this without, in some way, adjusting the CSS of the children.

Answer (score -3):

try use css `position: relative` in your children elements?
and use percentage in width and height.